# Visual Studio Code and jsconfig.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

I see in Visual Studio Code 0.5.0 that the **`/// <reference path="../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts"/>`** can be removed from the .js files and added into an overriding *jsconfig.json* file. I have therefore dropped the jsconfig.json file into the root directory of my project.

However, when I create the file *jsconfig.json* and add a line referring to the above path to the **jquery.d.ts** file and remove the **/// <reference path ....** from my .js files, I am not seeing the intellisense return. As I would expect it to with Visual Studio Code.

The jsconfig.json file I had created was:

```
{
    "files": [
        "../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Maybe I am missing the point of the *jsconfig.json* file.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to add "files" to your *jsconfig.json* file. The only reason you need to do that is if you want a specific set.

Instead, remove the files array.  It sounds like it still won't work at that point based on your description.  My assumption then is you do not have the .\typings\tsd.d.ts" file.  It seems to read that to references the correct files.  In order to get that, you need to do "tsd install node --save".

Comment: Thanks. It is just from what I read on VS Code website, the impression I got, was that by putting in files in jsconfig.json, the path to jquery.d.ts, would allow avoid adding the /// references to each file . The path to the jquery.d.ts, was the same one used by the /// reference.

Answer (score 3):

You need to adjust your file paths relative to jsconfig.js.

I.e. define files like:

```
{
    "files": [
        "typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Bah, needed longer to edit my comment. Anyway I have reread the comment - **We changed two things: You can now define a project using a jsconfig.json file and we optimistically load existing d.ts-files from you workspace.** from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vscode/archive/2015/07/06/vs-code-es6.aspx and I am wondering is VS code meant to pre load the typings from the typings sub directory. If it is then it doesn't seem to. If you are meant to have a jsconfig.json file to make it work, then I had assumed it would go in the root directory of the project.

Comment: ps - How to you add a return in using the editor or do you edit outside and then paste in?

Comment: I'm not sure what VC code blog means by "optimistically loading". What worked for me was placing jsconfig.js to project root and referencing d.ts-files relative to it (or project root).  My current setup actually references just one bundled "typings/tds.d.ts".

Comment: Re *"jsconfig.js"*: Do you mean *"jsconfig.json"*? If not, can you [address](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31498790/edit) it in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: True, it seems to be typo. This is very old case and I do not recall details for this. Syntax for sure is JSON so I think the file type extension should be too.